# Absolute positioning but only inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having issues with sticky javascript function which allows fixed positioning of the div.

This is the function:

```
$(function(){ // document ready
  if (!!$('.sticky').offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists
    var stickyTop = $('.sticky').offset().top; // returns number 
    $(window).scroll(function() { // scroll event
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number 
      if (stickyTop < windowTop) {
    $('.sticky').css({ position: 'fixed', width: 'inherit', top: 10 });
      } else {
    $('.sticky').css('position','static');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

But I need that to happen only inside the parent div, not the whole page.
Here is the example:

http://www.astroprodavnica.com/59/izrada-i-tumacenje-natalne-karte.html

It is the div on the right.

Comment: Absolute positioning in your question title and you asked for fixed position?? you need to change the title to fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you use fixed position you need to use *(relative parent position will not work with fixed child)*

```
if (windowTop > stickyTop 
  && windowTop < $('.right').offset().top + $('.right').outerHeight(true)) {
    $('.sticky').css({ position: 'fixed', width: 'inherit', top: 10 });
  }else if(windowTop < stickyTop ){
     $('.sticky').css('position','static');
  }else{
    $('.sticky').css('position','absolute').css('bottom', '0px');
  }
```

Comment: You are golden! :-) We are almost there - check the url now - the only thing that I would like to see as a functionality is to have that right sticky section 'stick' at the bottom of 'right' div and not to dissapear. Is that possible?

Comment: @Outlaw011 its depending on your .right column height  so assign the height for .right to be min-height: 1500px; for example and you will see it

Comment: @Outlaw011 you can use .data instead of .right on my code it will better to get a good height for it

Comment: Actually, at one point it just disappears, and i tried setting height to 800px without success. I am giving you the credit for this, but I really hope you can help me solve this...

Comment: Yu can check it out with .data in the sticky function, still not working 100% correctly. it should stick until the end of right, then stay there as we scroll the screen.

Comment: @Outlaw011 1st: Please don't check the answer as a right answer till it solve you problem .. 2nd: I updated my answer

Comment: Ok, check it out now... It stays there and it logs after leaving 'right' div

Comment: @Outlaw011 I think I got your point .. try the updated code and give .right style position relative  and height more than 1000 to notice it

Comment: Hmm, I did it - for some reason, when it reaches the end of right div it dissapears. It needs to stick there and scroll up as if it was static on that position.

Comment: @Outlaw011 this is a right one https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vnyx3gyj/1/

Answer (score 3):

Parent `div` should have `position: relative` or any other than `static`, which is used by default.

Then to position inside this parent, child should have `position: absolute`.

You can read more about positioning e.g. [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Comment: Hi SC, thanks on a prompt answer. I tried that and it didn't work because of thise JS. You can try on jfiddle and see for yourself. The JS need to be fixed somehow.

Comment: If you want me to check it please make an effort and at least prepare JSFiddle which is demonstrating that issue.